# Removing extra formatting from a python list element ( [''] )

Tags: python

Re-learning python after not using it for a few years - so go nice on me.
The basis, is I am reading in data from a .csv file, the information i am reading in is as follows

```
E1435
E46371
E1696
E27454
```

However, when using `print(list[0])` for example, it produces

```
['E1435']
```

I am trying to use these pieces of data to interpolate into an API request string, and the " [' '] " in them is breaking the requests - basically, I need the elements in the list to not have the square brackets and quotes when using them as variables.

My interpolation is as follows, in case the way I'm interpolating is the problem:

```
req = requests.get('Linkgoeshere/%s' % list[i])
```

**Edit;**
A sample of the data i'm using is listed above with "E1435, E46371" etc. each item in the csv is a new row in the same column.
As per a request, i have produced a minimal reproduction of my experience.

```
import csv
#list to store data from csv
geoCode = []
#Read in locations from a designated file
with open('Locations.csv','rt')as f:
  data = csv.reader(f)
  for row in data:
    geoCode.append(row)
i=0
for item in geoCode:
  #print the items in the list
  print(geoCode[i])
  i+=1
```

Comment: btw don't use `list` as a variable name. You are redefining the built-in `list`.

Comment: _basically, I need the elements in the list to not have the square brackets and quotes when using them as variables._ Don't just think of them as random extra characters, those have real meaning. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @AMC I appreciate they have real meaning, I suppose my wording was off in that case. From what i can tell, they (in this situation) signify elements of a sub-list. The solution marked as answer below produced my desired results, and i have since implemented something to flatten those lists. I'm now more interested in **why** it created sub-lists, and whether what i have done in the minimal reproduction was the problem, or if reading in from a csv creates a sub-list per row.

Comment: @Hades_S _From what i can tell, they (in this situation) signify elements of a sub-list._ "sublist" is a term we use to refer to nested lists, but it's really just a list like any other. _or if reading in from a csv creates a sub-list per row._ Almost, the `csv.reader` returns each row as a list, which becomes a "sublist" when you append it to `geoCode` (which should probably be named `geocode` or `geo_code`, by the way). Does that clarify things? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `list[i]` is itself a nested list, so you need another subscript to get to the element inside it:

```
print(list[i][0])
```

NB: Avoid naming variables `list` as it overrides the built-in `list` type. Try using a plural word like `codes` or `ids` instead.

Comment: That's Perfect, does what i need it to, much appreciated! Am i doing something wrong to create a nested list? I'm simply appending an element to a list of undefined size: "geoCode.append(row)" . Also to the NB, i only used "list[]" as a generic example, I am infact using a unique name for the actual project (geoCode, as shown above).

Comment: Yeah, it's better to correct the mistake at the source and flatten the sublists there.